# Particles.JS Background for Body of SharePoint Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have created this particles.js script that I want to use for one of my SharePoint pages, but I am unsure of how to get it to insert to cover the whole background. I tried inputting it as a a script editor web app but of course it only places it in the column that it is in. I have other script/content editors on the page as well and I am unsure if that is interfering, do I need to wrap it within my particles HTML or vice versa?

Here is my Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6pr37bt8/1/

Comment: Are you using classic or modern SharePoint?

Comment: @CallumCrowley classic

Comment: I tried setting my canvas to this `position : absolute; width:100%;
  height:100%; z-index:-1;` but unfortunately that was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. Confused as to why there are no code snippets available on this stack exchange site but on others. So because of that I will link the live JSFiddle.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dhytmpz5/1/

I had to place the particle div outside of everything else at the beginning of the HTML. Then like my comment to my question stated, I edited the CSS for canvas to be `position : absolute; width:100%;   height:100%; z-index:-1;`